# black screen with Stripe apple logo on OSX vmware workstation

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I had a running OSX on vmware workstation 11.

I restored my host win 10 and install vmware workstation 11 again, then copy osx folder to its older place on drive c:\

now when I play OSX on vmware, its loaded but at end show a black screen with Stripe apple logo.

whats the problem here ? 
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Answer (score 1):

problem was an update to vmware workstation 11 :
Unlocker207 
after install it problem solved.

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly just in case it's not clear to reader with the same problem you reported.

Comment: VMware Workstation does not allow running macOS in a VM.  Some people have made binary patches to Workstation to allow it.  Such binary patches obviously will break whenever an updated version of Workstation is installed.